# ImageView white src becomes transparent

Tags: android

I have the following in my layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
    android:background="@drawable/control_circle"/>
```

Here's the drawable for control_circle.xml:

```
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/control_normal"/>
    <size android:width="16dp" android:height="16dp"/>
</shape>
```

ic_star.png is just a white star I got from [Material Icons](https://www.google.com/design/icons/index.html#ic_star). What I'm getting is a blue circle (expected) with a star cutout instead of a white star; i.e. I can see stuff behind this icon through the star cutout. It basically looks like it's using a porter duff mode of DestOut with the src as the source and background as the dest.

Anybody know how I can get it to just show a white icon?

UPDATE:

Here's what I got:
[image: Screen shot]

You'll see here at the bottom that the FAB in the home page (with the + icon) is overlayed with a full screen dialog using a 70% alpha and some more action buttons (similar to the Inbox by Gmail app). But the star icon which is all white gets translated into a transparent area in the ImageView.

Comment: by default `ImageView` does not use any porter duff stuff, post your images of what you got and what you wanna get

Comment: Wow, I figured it out. So the original dialog layout I used a white background and set the alpha to 70%. Instead I now set the background to #AAFFFFFF and that fixed it. Seems that setting the alpha of a layout will affect the alpha of the image sources in ImageViews nested inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here was setting the background to the dialog's layout as white and setting android:alpha to 70%. This causes all nested ImageViews to use the same alpha. Instead, I needed to set the alpha to the background color of the dialog via a color like #AAFFFFFF.